# How to activate linux conda and run python script from Windows Powershell

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed wsl ubuntu, setup a conda env, and run a python script without problem.
[image]

Now I tried to integrate it into my pipeline and run this command through PowerShell in Windows with

`wsl.exe python /mnt/x/projects/EpiMiner/scEpilock/code/utils/e04_variant_impact.py --cell TLymphocyte1_CD8+ --snp /mnt/x/projects/EpiMiner/scEpilock/snp.txt --path /mnt/x/projects/EpiMiner/atac --out /mnt/x/users/shangl02/Test`

it failed since the python used here was not the wsl ubuntu conda python (I have trouble to phrase it nicely). So I guess my question is how to activate linux conda env and run python script from powershell in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `conda run` command. Use it like this: `conda run -n your_env python your_script.py`.

For more info checkout `conda run --help`

I run my script in WSL conda env from windows like this:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu -u my_user_name sh -c ". ~/.profile && /home/my_user_name/miniconda3/bin/conda run -n my_env python my_pyscript.py"
```

Comment: thanks! Nice trick with sourcing `~/.profile` at the beginning. In my case I use `bash` so it would be `source ~/.bashrc`